# Get TFS changesets in for a folder groups by user with count

Tags: tfs, source-control-explorer

I am on a large unorganized project with over 50 Visual Studio projects.  I want to see who has *really* been working on each of the projects.  My thought it to get a list of all the check-ins for a project and see the distinct users.  Hopefully, I can get a count of checkins per-user/per-project.

How can I do this in TFS?

Or, can I export the changesets for a TFS folder?  I see them with find-Changset but don't see how to export them.

Comment: Are all projects in one team project?

Comment: yes.  If I could export the results from 'find changesets' I could manually search each folder and let Excel aggregate the counts by user.